# Trying to create a "folder-like" gui using html5 drag and drop (Angular 4)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, nested, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to develop a certain web application that uses HTML5 drag and drop API. My application should give the user the abillity to drag and drop items to a certain "Drop Zone" block and also the abillity to drag items on other items to create folders, and items on folders, and folders on folders and so on... (inside the drop zone block of course).

I tried using 2 arrays of items, one for all of the applications and one for the selected application (that has been dragged to drop zone).

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-drag-and-drop?file=src/app/app.component.html

stuck here.

Expected output should be like mobile phones when you can drag one app on another to create a new folder (just a bit stronger when you can drag folder on folder to create a big folder containing both)

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-drag-and-drop-3gu1w3?file=src/app/app.component.ts), just added `event.stopPropagation();` and items array into each app.

Comment: I'm looking at the blitz you've created. It doesn't fulfill my question.. I need the functionality to drag items over items (inside the drop zone) and then to create folders according to this.

Comment: It's only the initial logic (2 levels) from here you need to use recursion to achieve your goal, about "creating folders" its just items over items, so I think it's only a graphical integration so you can see the "folders", I'm gonna work on the blitz but gonna take me some time to complete. =)

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm looking forward to it. thanks for the help. I'm starting to get it but still need to see a full example (cause I get confused with the recursion part)